# Application storing keystrokes in either iPad/iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

Anybody can tell where iOS application stores all the key pressed in "text box" if that text box is not set as secure.

I would want to know the path in iPhone/iPad system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not the text field is secure, the text is in the `text` property of the `UITextField`. It is unclear what you are asking

Comment: Thanks for the response. see I wanted to know if an application can store the text entered in any text box present in it. Can i find how it stores that key data(like which keys have been pressed) from a device in case device is jailbroken ?

Comment: I don't know about jail breaking, but I doubt there is any "store" of all keystrokes

Comment: Typically, intercepting key presses and storing them would be a wrapper around your app. You can always test to see if the device is jail broken but cannot test to see if the jail broken device is intercepting your key presses.

Comment: Paulw11- Actually what I am looking here is, any log file or cached copy of all the key's being pressed on a specific text box present in application

Comment: Dominic- thanks for responding. I understand it is some kind of wrapper around application, but the point is, does that wrapper stores any keys or keyword searches in application?